# 100GB free space on NFS server, but can't write even an empty file

Tags: redhat

[image]

In my Production NFS server more 100GB free, but I can't write even an empty file on that drive. Please find the attached image for clarification. Now I have fixed the issue by removing some folders on that drive.

Comment: No image attached. I would assume if has mounted correct check permissions.

Comment: Please copy & paste *code* (four spaces before every line) not *images* in questions; you really should edit your question to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Use both `df` & `df -i` after reading [df(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html); perhaps you have too many [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) in your [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). See also [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) so run `stat -f`

Perhaps you have reached some [disk quota](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota). See also [quota(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/quota.1.html)

Consider using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find the failing syscall and its `errno`